# C - Assigining values to struct (not pointer) fetched from array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

First of all, I'd be surprised if this is not a duplicate. I have, however, not succeeded in finding a question that describes what I'm trying to do.

So here it is. I'm trying to create an array of structs with a defined length SIZE:

```
#define SIZE 100

struct Link {
    int number;
    int id;
};

struct Link links[SIZE];
```

Then I'm trying to run through it and assign values to each struct's members:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    struct Link link = links[i];        
    link.number = i;
    link.id = i + 100;
}
```

But the values are not assigned, they're always 0.

This seems to work, however:

```
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        #define link links[i]
        link.number = i;
        link.id = i + 100;
    }
```

but `#define link links[i]` keeps giving me an error that `i` cannot be resolved.

Am I ignoring an obvious solution to this? I'm greatful for any help, guys!

This is part of a school assignment, and I believe we're not allowed to change `links` to be an array of pointers.

**EDIT**

I've found that doing `links[i].something = something_else` works, but the `struct Link` really have a lot of members, making that solution somewhat messy. But if it's the only alternative, I'll go with it.

Comment: `struct Link link` is local value.

Comment: With that, do you mean that values I assign to it will disappear outside of the scope in which they're assigned?

Comment: @Plasma your loop makes a copy of the uninitialized struct, changes your copy, and that's it. So, you're not modifying your array, you're only using it to source your copies. Use BLUEPIXY's answer instead. Your `#define line links[i]` works because that effectively _is_ BLUEPIXY's answer.

Comment: @Plasma That's right. It is not valid outside of the scope. Also note that the original would not be changed if a copy of the value type(`struct`) is made.

Comment: on `struct Link link = links[i]`, `link` is not a reference the the `i`th element of `links`. It's another variable to which you are now copying the current value of `links[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    links[i].number = i;
    links[i].id = i + 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of structure elements to assign to, and want to type a bit less (not that it changes much, that's what copy/paste is for), you could also use:

```
int i;
struct link *link;
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    link=links+i;                  // which is equivalent to link=&links[i];
    link->number = i;              // equivalent to (*link).number = i;
    link->id = i + 100;
}
```